# Grant permission to everyone with Amazon S3 upload

Tags: android, amazon-s3

After uploading a file with the TransferUtility for Amazon S3, I can't use the file.

```
Request failed 403: Forbidden
```

When I go to my bucket and check Permissions on the right, it only shows me.
When I add everyone, I can access the file without problems.

I was searching for a way to grant permission while uploading, but could find one for Android.

I found an answer for C# which leads me to this:

```
CannedAccessControlList cannedAccessControlList = CannedAccessControlList.BucketOwnerFullControl;
```

but I don't know where to add this..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to define a Bucket Policy that grants public access to a bucket, or a path within a bucket. That way, you do not need to specify the permissions on each individual object.

See: [Using Bucket Policies and User Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-iam-policies.html)

For example, this bucket policy would allow public access to any object stored in the `uploads` path:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"AddPerm",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/uploads/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

transferManager.upload(new PutObjectRequest("bucket name", "file name", "file path object").withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));